# 500 Server Error now occurring on existing Google App Engine site

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an existing GAE application that I've been running for months at www.sachinrekhi.com that just started returning the following 500 Server Error. I've changed nothing on the application (haven't done a deployment in 56 days). I checked the logs and there are no recent Errors in the logs to help get to the root cause. The App Engine status page seems to suggest everything is currently up, so doesn't seem to be an overall GAE issue.

There appear to be 0 running instances of the application. But even after I hit the site, a running instance doesn't seem to be automatically added. However, I'm below the rate limits for today, so I don't understand why an instance wouldn't automatically start.

How can I get to the bottom of the issue?

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the >query that caused it.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. There are 2 others who reported this
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/g1VinggHeqU
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/4f9mcNiErnM 
Takashi from Google responded to the second report.

Update:
At 16:37 PM Pacific my instances started back up, so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

More information on this issue can be found at http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/serving/2013/01/03#ae-trust-detail-helloworld-get-latency.